# Read S3 file with a period(.) in filename

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to read a text file from S3 which contains period in filename.

```
name1.name2-department.json
```

Following is my code

```
AmazonS3 amazonS3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2)
                .build();
S3Object s3Object = amazonS3Client.getObject("my-bucket",
                "folder/name1.name2-deptartment.json");
```

When I try to execute `getObject` method I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey; Request ID:
```

But there is no issues while read file names without period, for example `name1-dept.json` works fine

File names with period(.) should be handled with special case? AWS supportes reading files with period(.)?

Comment: Have you tried with v2 of the AWS Java SDK instead of v1?

Comment: I cannot use v2 of AWS SDK, it means changing all the other implementations. How does v2 differ from V1?

Answer (score 0):

According to AWS's S3 bucket [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-keys), a "." is a special character that is generally okay to use in your key/file name. So I do not think that is your issue.

You said that you are trying to read text from the file "name1.name2-department.json", however, when you are calling the `getObject()` method, you are trying to get the file "name1.name2-dept.json". This would cause the key/file to not be found.

Make sure that the file name in your S3 bucket matches the file name in your code.

Comment: There was a typo in question, both the file names are the same.